# Rails Foreign key setup question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-key-relationship

I'm just (re)starting playing around with Rails and I'm making a little card game app.  I cannot seem to figure out my Foreign Key setups.
Say I have 4 objects:
- Game
- Player
- Hand
- Card

A Game has many Players, which have many Hands which have many Cards.  But the cards are also independent of a Hand, Player and Game.
For example, I have 6 Cards in my database (1 to 6).  It is possible that Card 3 could be in 2 Players Hands in the same Game.

How can I set up my keys for this?  Should I just create another object for "CardInHand" to simplify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between cards and hands is the classic [`Has And Belongs To Many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) (HABTM).  When you have a HABTM relationship, there needs to be a table to manage the pairings (hands_cards, say, with just pairs of ids in it) but there need not be a corresponding model.

(Note that you'll need to create a migration to generate the hands_cards table yourself; it won't be created automatically.)

You do have the option, as you say, to create a separate model to represent a card being in a hand -- this is a `has_many :through` relationship -- but I would only do that if there's a special reason to model that relationship as a concrete object.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Best Practice for Rails is not to use foreign keys in the db, but to use validations on the model to ensure data correctness.

As the other answer explains what you'll want to set that up.

Comment: I think this is a misleading answer -- Rails absolutely uses foreign keys, it just doesn't create foreign key *constraints*.  An important distinction.  If my Hand table has a Player id in it, that's a foreign key, even if my database isn't enforcing that the Player id is valid.

Comment: Hmmm you're right - looks like I got confused and though that's what he was talking about. My bad.